# Escaping '“' with regular double quotes using Ruby regex

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

I have text that has these fancy double quotes: '“' and I would like to replace them with regular double quotes using Ruby gsub and regex.  Here's an example and what I have so far:

```
sentence = 'This is a quote, “Hey guys!”'  

I couldn't figure out how to escape double quotes so I tried using 34.chr:
sentence.gsub("“",34.chr).  This gets me close but leaves a back slash in front of the double quote:

sentence.gsub("“",34.chr) => 'This is a quote, \"Hey guys!”'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The backslashes are only showing up in `irb` due to the way it prints out the result of a statement.  If you instead pass the `gsub`ed string to another method such as `puts`, you'll see the "real" representation after escape sequences are translated.

```
1.9.0 > sentence = 'This is a quote, “Hey guys!”'  
 => "This is a quote, \342\200\234Hey guys!\342\200\235" 
1.9.0 > sentence.gsub('“', "'")
 => "This is a quote, 'Hey guys!\342\200\235" 
1.9.0 > puts sentence.gsub('“', "'")  
This is a quote, 'Hey guys!”
 => nil
```

Note also that after the output of `puts`, we see `=> nil` indicating that *the call to `puts`* returned `nil`.

You probably noticed that the funny quote is still on the end of the output to `puts`: this is because the quotes are two different escape sequences, and we only named one.  But we can take care of that with a regex in `gsub`:

```
1.9.0 > puts sentence.gsub(/(“|”)/, 34.chr)
This is a quote, "Hey guys!"
 => nil
```

Also, in many cases you can swap single quotes and double quotes in Ruby strings -- double quotes perform expansion while single quotes do not.  Here are a couple ways you can get a string containing just a double quote:

```
1.9.0 > '"' == 34.chr
 => true 
1.9.0 > %q{"} == 34.chr
 => true 
1.9.0 > "\"" == 34.chr
 => true
```