# Escaping double quotes in Ruby's gsub

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

I'm trying to minify some inline JSON as part of my HTML minifier. How do I make this:

```
>      {"@context": "http://schema.org",        "@type": "WebSite"}      <
```

Into this:

```
>{ "@context": "http://schema.org", "@type": "WebSite" }<
```

I've tried `gsub[/\", \s+\"/, ", "]`, `gsub[/"\"}"/, "\" }"]` and `gsub[/"\"}"/, "\" }"]` but that errors out.

```
syntax error, unexpected [, expecting ']' (SyntaxError)
[/"\"}"/, "\" }"]
 ^
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting keyword_end
```

## UPDATE

I've now also tried these but to no good:

```
[/>\s+{/, ">{ "]    # >      {     => >{
[/}\s+>/, " }<"]    # }      <     => }<
[%r/{"/, '{ %r/"']  # {"           => { "
[%r/"}/, '%r/" }']  # "}           => " }
[%r/",\s+/, ", "]   # ,        "   => , "
```

Resulting in:

```
syntax error, unexpected [, expecting ']' (SyntaxError)
[/}\s+>/, " }<"]    # }      <     => }<
 ^
```

Comment: have you tried `%r` ? See : http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Percent+Strings

Comment: Hi! Please see updated question. Thanks :)

Comment: What's the rationale for writing your own minifier? Are you aware of the intractable limitations of using regular expressions to "parse" HTML and JavaScript?

Comment: this might be a stupid question, but are you calling gsub with square brackets around the arg list? `'{ "@context": "http://schema.org", "@type": "WebSite" }'.gsub /\", \s+\"/, ", "` works fine for me

Comment: @FredWillmore the square brackets are just to split the gsubs into arrays I think?

Comment: You need to use parentheses, not square brackets, around your argument list for `gsub`

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest a different approach:

```
require JSON
str = '{"@context": "http://schema.org",        "@type": "WebSite"}'
new_str = JSON.parse(str).to_json
puts new_str

> {"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"WebSite"}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need to use it like I do, it's a Rack middleware. Please see updated question.

Answer (score 1):

Use a %r Regexp literal to escape all characters but one :

```
a = '{"@context": "http://schema.org",        "@type": "WebSite"}'

a.gsub(%r/{"/, '{ "').gsub(%r/"}/, '" }').gsub(/\s+/, ' ')
#=> { "@context": "http://schema.org", "@type": "WebSite" }
```

using `%r{ ... }` escapes all characters but `{` and `}`,same goes for `/`, `(`, etc ...

Answer (score -1):

credit : [Escaping '“' with regular double quotes using Ruby regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909924/escaping-with-regular-double-quotes-using-ruby-regex)

It will escapes double quotes

```
gsub(/("|")/, 34.chr)
```